# How to sort array values inside a class

Tags: c++

I wanted to sort the inputs by ascending order. but it seems to be sorting the integers only.. I based the sorting method on Bubble Sort.. Sorry if my post is too messy.. My first post here :(

```
using namespace std;

struct movies_t{

    string title;
    int year;
}films[3];

void printmovie (movies_t movie);

int main ()
{
    string mystr;
    int n,t;
    string d;

    for(n=0;n<3;n++)
    {

        cout <<"Enter title:";
        getline(cin,films[n].title);
        cout <<"Enter year:";
        getline(cin,mystr);
        stringstream (mystr)>> films[n].year;

    }

    for(n=0;n<3;n++)
    {
        for(int y=0; y<3; y++)
        {
            if(films[n].year < films[y].year)
            {
                t = films[n].year;
                films[n].year = films[y].year;
                films[y].year = t;
            }

            if(films[n].title < films[y].title)
            {
                d = films[n].title;
                films[n].title = films[y].title;
                films[y].title = d;
            }
        }
    }

    cout <<"\n You have entered these movies:\n";
    for(n=0;n<3;n++)
        printmovie (films[n]);
    return (0);
}

void printmovie(movies_t movie)
{
    cout <<movie.title;
    cout <<"("<<movie.year<<")\n";
}
```

The Ouput

```
     Enter title:a
     Enter year:2001
     Enter title:d
     Enter year:2011
     Enter title:f
     Enter year:2005

     You have entered these movies:
     a(2001)
     d(2005)
     f(2011)
```

I wanted the output to be:

```
     You have entered these movies:
     a(2001)
     f(2005)
     d(2011)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should compare film's year, but replace the whole elements, not only their titles, like this:

```
d = films[n];
films[n] = films[y]; 
films[y]= d;
```

Comment: this answer breaks the relationship between title and year

Answer (score 1):

A more efficient or cleaner way to sort your array could be to add the operator < to the structure and then sort with std::sort. that'd also solve your problem with your sorting function.

```
struct movies_t{

    string title;
    int year;

    bool operator<(const movies_t& rhs) const
    {
        if (year < rhs.year)
            return true;
        if (year > rhs.year)
            return false;
        return title < rhs.title;
    }

}films[3];
```

replace sorting code with:

```
#include <algorithm>

std::sort(films, films + n);
```